# How to serialize only selected properties when using web services in ASP.NET application

Tags: web-services, serialization, asp.net-ajax

In most cases we are using ASP.NET web services (System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService) in our AJAX based web applications. This approach brings a major advantage providing automatically all the server-side classes (used in the web service methods) on client side in form of JavaScript alternatives (JavaScript classes with appropriate namespace).

However, in our applications we are working with classes based on a 3rd party framework. These classes inherit many unserializable properties that makes them unusable for the automatic web service serialization into JSON and back once sent to the client side.

Is there a way to define the list of properties to serialize to JSON and back (once send to client and back) for appropriate class?

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches I can think of:

1. Wrap your 3rd party classes in your
   own classes where you can control
   what properties get exposed to the
   serializer.  This has the benefit
   that it should allow you to expose
   the data with any web service
   implementation (e.g. JSON, XML).
2. Create a [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx)
   class that will let you implement
   custom serialization and
   deserialization of the third party
   classes.

Comment: +1 to #1. You can make the DTO approach even easier by using AutoMapper to map between the third-party classes and your own DTO classes automatically.